# Read data from grid table in windows apllication using automation anywhere

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I need to extract the data from the specific row and column in the grid table which is in the windows application using automation anywhere. how to extract the data from specific row and column of the table.

Comment: why do you tag the question with uipath-studio if related to automation anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your question would have been more clear if you could have attached any sample of your current code and the table you are talking about.

You could try any of the below approach after Capturing the table using object cloning,

```
1   **Comment: //Extract complete table to CSV**
2   Object Cloning: Get Table(Extract Table) "" to csv and store at "Test.csv" from window 'Stocks - Bloomberg - Internet Explorer'; Source: Window; Play Type: Object


3   **Comment: //Get cell by Index**
4   Object Cloning: Get Cell Text By Index of Table "" where row:"1" column:"1" from window 'Stocks - Bloomberg - Internet Explorer'; Assign to variable "$Prompt-Assignment$"; Source: Window; Play Type:Object


5   **Comment: //Get cell by Text**
6   Object Cloning: Get Cell Index By Text of Table "" where Text:"hello" from window 'Stocks - Bloomberg - Internet Explorer'; Assign to variable "$Prompt-Assignment$"; Source: Window; Play Type:Object
```